# Launching my webview app when my website url cliks or open

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have a website and WebView app based on it. my website link is like http://website.in/. when the user tries to open this link and associated links like http://website.in/post_name/, I want android to show him a chooser dialog where he can choose option to open that link using my application when he installed the app. please give me the code for android studio.

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com.  At-least post your code or your effort what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deeplink this URL into the HomeActivity or MainActivity of your app. In your manifest's main-activity's declaration section add below entered properties.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="website.in"
                android:pathPattern="/.*"
                android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                                                                      
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                    android:host="website.in"
                    android:scheme="http" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: it's Working when remove www from url , Thanks for help.

Comment: i need one more help...  when open my link like http://website.com/post_name/  throug my webview app but only main url is openong like http://website.com/. how to resolve this and give me the code for it.

Comment: updated answer, try now

Comment: when its added whole code not working....

Comment: Try now, updated pattern is working

Comment: how to deeplink url...

Comment: you can check my updated answer. And this is not a "please do my code" platform, try things and ask help where you stuck